# Floating button and "bended" navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, navbar

[image]
I'm working on a web project(using `html`, `css`, `javascript`) and want to something like the image above in my project for mobile users. I've done some research but can't quite find the solution.

Is there a specific name for this kind of design ? Can I recreate it with just  `html` `css` `javascript` ?

Comment: Are you referring to the rounded border on the buttons?

Comment: It's about the bended edge of the bottom navigation bar where button floating on

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way that I can think of for the bend effect instead of having to play around with clip paths all day would be to create an image of the background with the bend in it as you would like in Photoshop or something similar, export it as a PNG then use that image as the background for the div. It must be PNG or SVG to ensure transparency in the bend.

As for the buttons in the bottom two images, I would use flexbox to space the buttons evenly and then translate the floating button upwards to the desired position. Something like this:

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.button {
    transform: translateY(-1.8rem);
}
```